# How to solve "Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have bunto-sitemap installed." on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

> I'm trying to use [Bunto](http://buntowaf.tk/) on my Windows 10 computer but I get a ***Dependency Error***!

**Error**

Here the output (error):

```
> bundle exec bunto serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/Aahash/Downloads/aahash.tk/_config.yml
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have bunto-sitemap or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Bunto as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- bunto-sitemap' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://buntowaf.tk/help/!
bunto 3.2.1 | Error:  bunto-sitemap
```

**My environment**

This is my Ruby and Gems versions:

```
> ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]

> gem -v
2.6.8
```

**Code**

My `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem 'bunto'
```

**Output**

This is my output of `bundle install`:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using sass 3.4.23
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using wdm 0.1.1
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using kramdown 1.13.2
Using liquid 3.0.6
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using rouge 1.11.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using bundler 1.13.6
Using bunto-sass-converter 2.0.0
Using rb-inotify 0.9.8
Using pathutil 0.14.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using bunto-watch 1.0.0
Using bunto 3.2.1
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 19 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot some gems in your `Gemfile`!

Comment: What gems do I need extra?

Comment: Read my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43573189/5157221.

Answer (score 3):

**You forgot to add `gem 'bunto-sitemap'` in your `Gemfile`!**

---

You should also use the [Windows Directory Monitor (WDM)](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm) gem!

> ***Info:*** Windows Directory Monitor (WDM) is a thread-safe ruby library which can be used to monitor directories for changes on Windows. It's mostly implemented in C and uses the Win32 API for a better performance!

---

Change the content in your `Gemfile` from this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem 'bunto'
```

to this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby RUBY_VERSION

gem 'bunto'
gem 'bunto-sitemap'

## Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a different gem, if the gem is installed it could be possible that for whatever the reason the bundle is not picking it up.

To make sure that the bundle recognizes it try using the following command:

```
sudo bundle add bunto-sitemap
```

After that check the bundle and if it is showing there as of now try the operation you were trying to run again. It should wor